# Strange issue with bridges on Ubuntu server and libvirt; looks like MAC address conflict

Tags: ubuntu, networking, vlan, bridge, libvirt

We have been using bridges and libvirt VMs for a long time (starting with Ubuntu 16.04). Recently, we have encountered a problem with bridges (on VLAns). We have not yet identified what conditions cause the problem to appear. Some work, some don't.

The problem is that the VM is not able to talk to the upstream router. However, the VM can talk to the bridge on the host. The router also can talk to the bridge on the host. Router, bridge and VM use static IP addresses on the same subnet.

There is a single physical ethernet connection between the router and the host. The bridge uses a VLAN on that link. The bridge normally does not have an IP address on the host - we added it for debugging.

The problem looks like a MAC address conflict on the bridge. The ARP request (broadcast) gets through both ways. The ARP response (distinct destination) gets through to the router, but not to the VM (not seen on bridge).

We use ifupdown (not netplan). This is for legacy reasons.

The VM is created with `virt-install`.

Some of the hosts have been upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and then 20.04. Others started with 18.04 or 20.04. The problem seems to be more likely on a direct install of 20.04. It works on one host with 5.4.0-137-generic #154-Ubuntu, but not on another with 5.4.0-146-generic #163-Ubuntu. But we don't know if that is consistent.

On host:

```
2: wan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:21:0b:35:ae:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.200.5/26 brd 172.16.200.63 scope global wan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 172.16.200.6/26 scope global secondary wan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4a21:bff:fe35:ae51/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

11: wan0.202@wan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master br-client state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:21:0b:35:ae:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

9: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br-client state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:6c:23:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet6 fe80::fc54:ff:fe6c:23ef/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

12: br-client: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:21:0b:35:ae:51 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.202.231/24 brd 192.168.202.255 scope global br-client
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::4a21:bff:fe35:ae51/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

On VM:

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:6c:23:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.202.234/24 brd 192.168.202.255 scope global enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::5054:ff:fe6c:23ef/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

libvirt networking on host:

```
 Interface   Type     Source      Model    MAC
--------------------------------------------------------------
 vnet0       bridge   br-client   virtio   52:54:00:6c:23:ef
```

**Update**:

The physical interface (wan0) on the host seems to not handle frames destined with the VM MAC address. tcpdump on wan0 shows the VLAN frames when the destination is the bridge's MAC address, but tcpdump does not show any VLAN frames with the destination of the VMs MAC address. tcpdump on the router shows that the frames with the VMs MAC are sent on the correct wire.

How is the MAC address of the VM passed to the virtual switch that handles frames from the wire?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a few things you can try, first check if the MAC address is allowed by the bridge `bridge fdb show br-client` if its missing just add it `bridge fdb add 52:54:00:6c:23:ef dev br-client`,

also check the bridge configuration like this bridge is created with `wan0` but it should be with `wan0.202` fix it accordingly, then you can verify MAC conflict between the host, vm, etc...

also check the host's iptables and ebtables rules for blocking rules for the VM MAC address. then you can also ensure that your network interface is configured to use the proper source bridge and MAC

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:6c:23:ef'/>
  <source bridge='br-client'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Comment: We checked all this. We also compared with two other systems where it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

We decided to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 (it was on the horizon anyway), and the problem went away. The VLAN, bridge and VM all worked as expected.

All I can speculate is that there is some subtle bug introduced between `#154-Ubuntu` and `#163-Ubuntu`, and fixed in Ubuntu 22.04 (`#76-Ubuntu`).

It is frustrating not to know, but we had to move on.